# set hour, minute and seconds to exact numbers in sql

Tags: sql, datetime, random

I am populating my databae with dummy information for testing purposes, thanks to `http://mitchelsellers.com/blogs/2008/09/12/creating-random-sql-server-test-data.aspx` And it is working, however my date is randomized and get random years/months but allways the current time, a few examples exctracted from my database:

```
2017-05-30 16:41:53.190
2017-07-21 16:41:53.193
2016-04-23 16:41:53.193
```

however my application using these dates must have them in the form of

```
2017-05-30 16:00:00.000
2017-07-21 01:30:00.000
2016-04-23 04:45:00.000
```

In other words the date is currently fine, but the `minute` should be on of `00,15,30,45` and `seconds` and `miliseconds` should allways be `00`.

Any way to add random times on the format above to my sql?

My current SQL logic is as follows:

```
DECLARE @RowCount INT
DECLARE @RowString VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @Random INT
DECLARE @Upper INT
DECLARE @Lower INT
DECLARE @InsertDate DATETIME
DECLAre @LoopThisManyTimes INT

SET @Lower = -360 /* move 360 days backwards */
SET @Upper = 360 /*  move 360 days forward */
SET @RowCount = 0 /* start the counter at 0 */
SET @LoopThisManyTimes = 10 /* set the number of posts to add */

USE [Scheduler]
TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[Appointments] /* clear table for testing purposes */
WHILE @RowCount < @LoopThisManyTimes /*loop and add to table */
BEGIN
SET @RowString = CAST(@RowCount AS VARCHAR(10))
    SELECT @Random = ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower -1) * RAND() + @Lower), 0)
    SET @InsertDate = DATEADD(dd, @Random, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do the calculation in seconds rather than days.  Here is one way:

```
WHILE @RowCount < @LoopThisManyTimes /*loop and add to table */
BEGIN
    SET @RowString = CAST(@RowCount AS VARCHAR(10));
    SELECT @Random = ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower -1)*60*60*24 * RAND() + @Lower*60*60*24), 0);
    SET @InsertDate = DATEADD(second, @Random, GETDATE());
END;
```

EDIT:

If you want fixed minutes:

```
WHILE @RowCount < @LoopThisManyTimes /*loop and add to table */
BEGIN
    SET @RowString = CAST(@RowCount AS VARCHAR(10));
    SELECT @Random = ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower -1)*4*24 * RAND() + @Lower*4*24), 0);
    SET @InsertDate = DATEADD(minute, @Random*15, CAST(GETDATE() as DATE));
END;
```

I think that arithmetic is right.

Comment: So close now, excellent answer, now I got random timestrokes but i need minutes to allways be 00, 15, 30 or 45 and second + milisecond allways 00 and 000 respectivly. A great start in the right direction, thanks.

Comment: @darrrrUC: Change `60*60*24` to `60/15*60*24` and the `DATEADD` to `(second, CAST(@Random*15 AS INTEGER), GETDATE())` to get 15 second increments

Comment: They are still not rounded :)

Comment: @darrrrUC Yep, you need to cast first: `CAST(@Random AS INTEGER) *15`